# Unexpected array element when inserting into a PostgreSQL database

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, api

I'm working on an API. I receive all the information from that API. The api contain the information about cities I want to store the data of the **result which is present below the meta** in postgres like each row will become the row of database using python but I receive error.

the sample of response I get from the api

```
{
'meta': {'license': 'CC By 4.0', 'name': 'openaq-api', 'website': 'https://docs.openaq.org/'},
'results': [
    {'city': 'Amsterdam', 'count': 71125, 'country': 'NL', 'locations': 14},
    {'city': 'Antofagasta', 'count': 3416, 'country': 'CL', 'locations': 1},
    {'city': 'Arica', 'count': 1682, 'country': 'CL', 'locations': 1},
    {'city': 'Ayutthaya', 'count': 3880, 'country': 'TH', 'locations': 1},
    {'city': 'Badhoevedorp', 'count': 7862, 'country': 'NL', 'locations': 1},
    ...
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
import openaq
import psycopg2
import json

conn = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                        password="root",
                        host="localhost",
                        database="xyz")
cursor = conn.cursor()
print("Connected")

api = openaq.OpenAQ()
status, resp = api.cities()
result = resp["results"]


for row in result:
    # print(row)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO openaq_api_data (openaq) VALUES (%s)", (Json(row),))
```

And here is my error:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO openaq_api_data (openaq) VALUES (%s)", (Json(row),))
    psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: malformed array literal: "{"country": "AD", "name": "Escaldes-Engordany", "city": "Escaldes-Engordany", "count": 193682, "locations": 2}"
    LINE 1: INSERT INTO openaq_api_data (openaq) VALUES ('{"country": "A...
                                                         ^
    DETAIL:  Unexpected array element.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Your title and your question ask different things: the title is clearly off-topic as too broad and opinion-based, but your question body seems to ask a specific question.

Comment: are storing the response in a single column ?

Comment: @RajatMishra yes

Comment: What type of column is `openaq`?

Comment: @Chris it's JSON

Comment: I tried both JSON and JSON[]

Comment: And what version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: when I chose the column json[] error was---> psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "id" of relation "openaq_api_data" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, {"country": "AD", "name": "Escaldes-Engordany", "city": "Escalde...).

Comment: @Chris version 13

Comment: @RajatMishra what if I want to make separate column for each one is it will be better

Comment: yeah that would be more simple and cleaner approach

Answer (score 1):

Note the syntax highlighting here:

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO openaq_api_data (openaq) VALUES (' + row + ')")
```

That whole string is just a string. If you want to pass in parameters, [provide a placeholder and then pass the arguments](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries):

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO openaq_api_data (openaq) VALUES (%s)", (row,))
```

Note that it is important to always pass parameters this way instead of including data using string interpolation to protect against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

So that's the parameter stuff, and it works out of the box for simple data types. But it looks like `row` here is actually a Python `dict`, in which case it will need a bit of extra care.

The best option here is [to use](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json) [the `Json` adapter](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json):

```py
from psycopg2.extras import Json

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO openaq_api_data (openaq) VALUES (%s)", (Json(row),))
#                                                                   ^^^^
```

Comment: an error:
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'

Comment: @Osamabillah, you're trying to save this as a single blob of JSON, right? Into a `json` column?

Comment: @Chris can you please check the question I tried my best to describe my problem

Comment: @Osamabillah, please see my updated answer

Comment: @Osamabillah, again, please update your _question_. Code and error messages are very hard to read in comments.

Comment: @Chris can you please check it